# How to store a enumerations in smart contracts with ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, storage

How to store enumeration in smart contract with ink!
I have a field in smart contract with type `Mapping<AccountId, Enum>`, I tried to use guide https://ink.substrate.io/datastructures/custom-datastructure, but I don't understand how I should pull, push and clear Enum values in storage by pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current version of the ink! you need to implement `SpreadLayout`, `PackedLayout`, and `StorageLayout`. You can derive implementation of those traits like [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/3c267d68a413cb25ca87a0ca1e014a52543971a2/examples/multisig/lib.rs#L102) or implement it manually.

But after resolving [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1134) maybe you need to derive other traits or use a macro. More details about the new version you can find with linked pull requests=)

Answer (score 1):

Just derive this trait to Enum or use this code:

```
  impl SpreadLayout for Enum {
    const FOOTPRINT: u64 = 2;

    fn pull_spread(ptr: &mut KeyPtr) -> Self {
        Self::from(SpreadLayout::pull_spread(ptr))
    }

    fn push_spread(&self, ptr: &mut KeyPtr) {
        SpreadLayout::push_spread(self, ptr);
    }

    fn clear_spread(&self, ptr: &mut KeyPtr) {
        SpreadLayout::clear_spread(self, ptr);
    }
}
```